# Как можно сделать текст на объекте

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать текст на объекте, подобно этому скриншоту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: UI Объекты только для Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно с делать при помощи TextMeshPro